# How to send a blob link with nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, email, nodemailer

I have a problem with nodemailer, I want to send a blob link to download a pdf only, nodemailer needs http: // in front of the link, my blob link works but the link is not clickable in my mail. Do you know a tip or solution?

Thank you in advance for your help

```js
    const {subject, message, customerEmail, pdf} = req.body
    

    // Create a SMTP transporter object
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
        port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: '...',
            pass: '...'
        }
    });

    // Message object
    let mail = {
        from: 'Sender Name <sender@example.com>',
        to: 'Recipient <recipient@example.com>',
        subject: subject,
        text: `${message} lien de téléchargement du devis : ${pdf}`,
        html: `<p><b>${message}</b></p></br><a href="${pdf}" target="_blank">téléchargez votre devis</p>`,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error occurred. ' + err.message);
            return process.exit(1);
        }

        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    });


    res.json({send: "true"})
```

**blob uri :**

blob:http://localhost:3000/e92e4e22-31ac-4740-b7fa-e0fc06ee08d7

Comment: A blob URL will not work for anybody else, just you. And only inside the browser that created it. If you want to send out a working link, the PDF needs to actually exist on the server, and the server needs to be reachable from outside your own LAN (localhost:3000 only works on your own computer). **You also shouldn't publicly post your actual login and password on the internet...**

Comment: Hi, ok thank you :)